# My computers internet hasnt been working correctly

Tags: windows, networking, dns, internet

My computer Internet has been acting weird this week. The first time I noticed this was when I opened a program and it show me a cryptic error message and some images where not loading. Then when I searched up the error message Google couldn't connect to the website but after a couple of tries it worked. The same Internet works fine on other devices.

Can someone help me it very annoying.

Things I have tried:

- Troubleshooting with windows Troubleshooting tool
- Resetting the network adapter
- Clearing the dns cache
- Resetting the router

Thanks

Comment: Did you scan fully for viruses?

Comment: Ok I'll try scanning my computer.

Comment: Look in the Event Viewer for related messages.

Comment: 1. Show the "cryptic error message" in the question. 2. Try different DNS resolution, e.g., change from automatic DNS lookup to 1.1.1.1 (Cloiudflare) or *vice versa*. 3. Try a different application, e.g., Firefox instead of Edge.